# Handling using Retrofit + Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm learning to use the Retrofit library for different tasks, but don't fully understand how it works yet.
The main task is to get the body if the response code is 200, overwise (all other codes) just set flag:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface APIService {

    @GET("/")
    suspend fun getRoot(): Response<ResponseBody>
}

...

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      
       ...

       
      button.setOnClickListener {

           val url = editText.text.toString()  
           //  url = "https://"+ "google.coN"
           val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .build() 
           val service = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
           ...

           CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                val response  = service.getRoot()
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful){
                        Ok = true // address is ok
                    } else {
                        Ok = false // this address dosnt exist
                                    }
                  ....      
                        }
                    }
              }
        }
}
```

Code works well (remastered from some tutor example) with good links  but the app crashes whenever the address is wrong or poorly formatted, it requires a well-formatted URL ("https://"+)

How to modify code and add an exception and do pre-format of URL?

*PS: Prob it is better to use OkHTTP directly, but I use integration
of GSON lib with this retrofit code, dropped for clarity*

Thanx.

Comment: a try catch block should help.

Comment: can you provide the error code?

Answer (score 2):

First, Create a `sealed` class to hold the result

```
sealed class ApiResult<out T : Any?>

data class Success<out T : Any?>(val data: T) : ApiResult<T>()

data class ApiError(val exception: Exception) : ApiResult<Nothing>()
```

Now write a helper function to map `okhttp` response to `ApiResult`

```
suspend fun <T : Any> handleApi(
    call: suspend () -> Response<T>,
    errorMessage: String = "Some errors occurred, Please try again later"
): ApiResult<T> {
    try {
        val response = call()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            isConnectedToNetwork = true
            response.body()?.let {
                return Success(it)
            }
        }
        response.errorBody()?.let {
            try {
                val errorString  = it.string()
                val errorObject = JSONObject(errorString)
                return ApiError(
                    RuntimeException(if(errorObject.has("message")) errorObject.getString("message") else "Error occurred, Try again Later"))
            } catch (ignored: JsonSyntaxException) {
                return ApiError(RuntimeException(errorMessage))
            }
        }
        return ApiError(RuntimeException(errorMessage))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        if (e is IOException) {
            isConnectedToNetwork = false
        }
        return ApiError(RuntimeException(errorMessage))
    }
}
```

Finally, use below to code to access the result

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
      val result: ApiResult<ResponseBody>  = handleApi( { service.getRoot() } )
      when(result){
          is ApiResult.Success -> // result.data will give you ResponseBody
          is ApiResult.ApiError -> // result.exception will provide the error
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few things which can help you with this, it will be more efficient:

1. Create a view model and create an instance of that in your activity.
2. In the view model, create a method for executing background tasks, like this:

   `private fun loadNetworkRequest(block: suspend () -> Unit): Job {`
           `return viewModelScope.launch {`
                    `try {`
                          `block()`
                        `}catch (ex: Exception) {`
                          `Toast.makeText(appContext, ex.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`
                        `}`
            `}`
   `}`
3. Add the `suspend` keyword for the request in the service file, which you want to execute using this method.

   `@GET("category/")`
   `suspend fun getCategories(): Response<CategoryResponseModel>`
4. Execute the request in the view model, like this:

   `fun performRequest(callback: (Boolean) -> Unit) {`
       `loadNetworkRequest {`
               `val response = service.getRoot()`
               `callback.invoke(response.isSuccessful)`
        `}`
   `}`
5. Call the request method in the activity.

   ```
   button.setOnClickListener {
     ....

      viewModel.performRequest { response ->

           // ok = response
       }
   }
   ```